# How do I solve triple integrals when given no function?

Tags: integration

I got this assignment:

It is set, that:

0 < b <= c

Now, I have to calculate the volume of the figure given by:

x >= 0, y >= 0, x + y <= b and x + y <= z <= c

I learnt that I $$\iiint{f(x,y,z)} dxdydz$$

is the same as
$$\iiint_{0}^{f(x,y)}{f(x,y)} dxdy$$

I'm not really sure what to do with the upper f(x,y) border here.
I would have said that I integrate the one to a z, to get this integral:
$$\iint{z}dxdy$$

However, I'm very uncertain here.

Can someone clear me up here?

Comment: You are asked for the volume of a region; this is the same as the triple integral of 1 over that region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be the plane region
$$
 D = \left\{(x,y) \mid x\geq0,\ y \geq0,\ x+y \leq b\right\}
$$
Then $E$ is “vertically simple” over $D$; by which we mean
$$
    E = \left\{(x,y,z)\mid (x,y) \in D,\ x+y \leq z \leq c\right\}
$$
(It helps to draw it.)

The volume of a solid is the triple integral of $1$ over that solid.  Therefore
$$\begin{split}
    \operatorname{Vol}(E) &= \iiint_E 1\,dV \\
    &= \iint_D \int_{x+y}^c 1\,dz\,dA \\
    &= \iint_D (c - x - y)\,dA \\
\end{split}$$

Now look more carefully at $D$.  We can describe it as
$$
    D = \left\{(x,y) \mid 0 \leq x \leq b, 0 \leq y \leq b-x\right\}
$$
So
$$\begin{split}
    \iint_D (c - x - y)\,dA = \int_0^b \int_0^{b-x} (c-x-y)\,dy\,dx
\end{split}$$